# Создать пару в MAP

Tags: c++, map, multiset

Смысл цикла: вводятся с клавиатуры s1 и s2.
Если mapT[s2] существует, то заносится в multiset значение.
Если mapT[s2] не существует, то создать пару mapT [s2]-ключ s1-значение.
Как это сделать?

```
    map <unsigned,multiset<int>,greater <int> > mapT;    
    while (i<n)
      {
        cin >> s1 >> s2;
        const auto found = mapT.find(s2);
        if (found != mapT.cend())
         {
          mapT[s2].insert(s1);
         }
         else
          {
           mapT.insert(s2,s1); ?????
          }
        i++;
      }
```

Comment: Непонятно, почему вы просто не вносите в любом случае s1 - раз у вас все равно multiset. Не понимаю ваши телодвижения - зачем?...

Comment: а если нет mapT с ключом s2 не существует, он автоматически создастся ?

Comment: Как только вы обратились через mapT[s2] - (пустой) элемент автоматически создается.

Comment: Вместо `greater <int>` стоит поставить `greater<unsigned>`.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не надо создавать специально, все [работает и так](https://ideone.com/Izr5Gh)...

```
map <unsigned,multiset<int>,greater <int>> mapT;

for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    mapT[rand()%10].insert(rand()%20);
}

for(auto m: mapT)
{
    cout << m.first << ": ";
    for(auto n: m.second) cout << n << " "; cout << endl;
}
```